# Context Variable support for Amazon lex chatbot

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, chatbot, amazon-lex

I am trying to build a chatbot version of AWS management console and wanted to see if I can use  things like region as environment variable instead of prompting it every time . Is there something like that ?

Answer (score 0):

You can define environment variables in AWS Lambda "Environment variables" section and use it in your code.
If you want to use custom environment variable in your code, you need to define it, and then use it in code like below:

```
import os
#assuming your environment variable is named as "name"
name = os.environ['name']
```

If you want to use pre-defined environment variables, you can use them as well. Example: AWS_REGION environment variable will give the name of region where lambda function is being executed. Like mine is giving me us-east-1 as output.

```
import os
os.environ['AWS_REGION']
```

Comment: I understand your point. But I am looking for something in the lex perspective. It shouldn’t be fully hard coded.

Comment: the only thing that's coming to mind is first setting the region in session attribute, then use it in Lex.

Comment: Session attribute ? Interesting - could you please provide a link or info to know more ?

Comment: @NaveenVijay http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lex/latest/dg/howitworks-manage-prompts.html